# MySQL Join two lists to check if a record exist

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've made an event system for my school that handles registrations for events.

Since we only want students to access sign up on the site, I've got a table called **potentialusers**. Every entry has a FullName and an Email. 
When a user signs up on the site, the site checks if the student's email is in the potentialusers table, and if it is, the user is added to the **users** table.

I've also got a table called **registrations**. Whenever a user registers for an event, it's added to this table.
An entry looks like this: **registrationid**, **eventid** (foreign key to the event table), **userid** (also a foreign key to the user table, not the potentialusers).

I want to search for a name with a LIKE statement and get a result list of users, a column that states if the user is registered for the event and a column that states if the user is even registered at all.

This is what I've tried (I added some comments in curly brackets):

```
SELECT FullName, Email from potentialusers
LEFT OUTER JOIN registrations ON (potentialusers.Email = registrations...{1})
WHERE events.eventid = '7'{2} AND potentialusers.Email LIKE = '%jazerix%';
```

**{1}** -> Here is the first problem since, the registration table doesn't contains a email column, only a reference to the user in the usertable, which contains the email.

**{2}**-> Just so we can separate events, 7 is only an example.

In the end I want to return something like this:

[image: sorry for the use of excel]

Comment: what are the fields that connect users to potentialusers ?

Comment: like a foreign key? or what? :)

Comment: what are the field names in users and potentialusers that connects are the foreign key relationship?

Comment: There is no direct relationship actually :/ My code just reads their name and email and adds it to the user table. The user table looks like this: useremail, password, banned, registrationdate, name, nuber, expirationdate

Comment: Is it true to say: if there is a record in the users table, we can find its corresponding record in potentialusers because the email exactly matches?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38576/discussion-between-jazerix-and-agrizzo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT
  p.FullName,
  p.Email,
  IF(u.userid IS NULL, 'False', 'True') RegisteredInSystem,
  IF(r.registrationid IS NULL, 'False', 'True') RegisteredInEvent
FROM potentialusers p
LEFT JOIN users ON p.Email = u.useremail
LEFT JOIN registrations r ON r.userid = u.id AND r.eventid = 7
WHERE p.FullName LIKE '%jazerix%'
```

Comment: Well! This sure is giving me some interesting results! :D However am I right when I'm saying that this just check if the user is actually registered in the system, because this is returning results that says "Registered", yet it has no registriondid associated with it. 

Also I changed p.Email to p.FullName :)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need ^^. If it's not asking too much, could you show me with your example above? :D

Comment: Oh my f***ing god! It worked, this really was worth the wait, thank you so much. Oh my god, you have no idea how much I'm smiling right now :D You guys rock, Mosty Mostacho and AgRizzo :D

Comment: Thanks... we know we're the best :P You can enjoy your parties and invite us now... just add us to the potentialusers table xD

Comment: Well, I've added you the the VIP list, so if you happen to come by Denmark tomorrow night, step on by and have a free beer^^ http://postimg.org/image/rybz5yacn/

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT potentialusers.FullName, potentialusers.Email
, IF(users.userid IS NULL, 'False', 'True') Registered
, registration.registrationid
FROM potentialusers
LEFT JOIN users
  ON potentialusers.Email = users. useremail
LEFT JOIN registrations
  ON registrations.userid = users.id
WHERE potentialusers.Email LIKE '%jazerix%'
  AND registrations.eventid = 7;
```

Comment: if i'am right this will never give you an result where registration will be false.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, because it is returning an error to me :(

Comment: @MostyMostacho Already fixed that in my query ^^, error persists

Comment: http://i42.tinypic.com/1zl6ptv.png
brugere = users and tilmeldinger = registrations. Some of my tables are danish and some aren't. Really confusing, sorry.

Comment: @Jazeriz I made a few tweaks to the code if AgRizzo doesn't mind. Try now.

Comment: you have nothing as a atribute in your case statement. it should be something line case some value when value=2 then something. your are missing that somevalue next to case

Comment: I found the error, with the like statement. The query ran, however it returned zery results, I'm currently trying the editing query @MostyMostacho did :)

Comment: knock yourself out - if this doesn't work, @Jazerix could you put a schema and some sample data in sqlfiddle?

Comment: well, I got above working, however it only returns the ones that are registered. I'm really a noob with SQL and especially sqlfiddle, but I'll give it a try, is there anything else I can do? :)

Comment: remove left from the joins

Comment: @MostyMostacho haha, that makes sense indeed, but then the question becomes, how do I get an idea of the user is registered to the event or not?

Comment: @JánSrniček - why remove the left joins?  They are there in theory to take into consideration unregistered (i.e., not in the users table) and those not going to an event (i.e., not in the registrations table)

Answer (score 0):

i think it should be like this

```
select 
pus.fullname,
rg.email,
case (select count(*) from registrations where usr.id=foreignkey_connection_to_this_table)
when 0 then 'FALSE'
when 1 then 'TRUE'
else 'MULTIPLE REGISTRATIONS'
end as registered,
rg.id as registration_id
from potentialusers pus 
join users usr using(foreign key connection to this table)
join event evt using(foreign key connection to this table)
join registrations rg using(foreign key connection to this table)
WHERE events.eventid = '7' AND potentialusers.Email LIKE = '%jazerix%';
```

i dont know your database model,so i white it in 'pseudo' sql.You must do some corections.

Comment: registrations doesn't hold a Email attribute :/